# How to check if userInput is an int

Tags: java

I am trying to output "Invalid value" if the MAX_VALUE I have is not an integer. Whenever I run this code, my overall output gets changed. I am wondering how to correctly do this.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ForLoopPractice {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.println("Print even values");
        System.out.print("Max value: ");
        MAX_VALUE = scnr.nextInt();
        
        for (int i=0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i + " ");
            
            }
        }
        while (!scnr.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Invalid value");
            scnr.next();
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Print a range of values");
        System.out.print("First Value: ");
        int firstVal = scnr.nextInt();
        
        System.out.print("Last Value: ");
        int secondVal = scnr.nextInt();
        
        for (int i = firstVal; i >= secondVal; i--) {
            System.out.println(i+ " ");
        
        }
        for (int i = firstVal; i <= secondVal; i++) {
            System.out.println(i+ " ");
        
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any input validation here... Can you elaborate what exactly you're trying to achieve, and what errors you're getting?

Comment: `Scanner.nextInt()` throws `InputMismatchException` if the next user input is not a valid integer

Comment: Aside from error details, as @Mureinik suggested, please edit your question to also point out where, exactly, you're having issues. There are several places where you're reading input, and it's not clear where your specific issue(s) are occurring.

Comment: Since the scanner would throw an exception if the input isn't integer, I would just recommend using a try-catch to locate this error and do something if this would happen.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Try-Catch block. `Scanner.nextInt()` throws `InputMismatchException` if the input isn't a number.

You can use a function to make sure the program doesn't go forward until the user has selected the proper input.

```
public static int getValidNumber(){
  try{
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
     int num;
     num = sc.nextInt();
     return num;
  } catch (InputMismatchException ex){
    System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
    return getValidNumber();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap "MAX_VALUE = scnr.nextInt();" with:

```
if (scnr.hasNextInt())
```

It will return true if the next value can be interpreted as an integer.

Answer (score -1):

While taking the input, you can check it by a method isDigit().
If N is a input given by user, check it by System.out.print(Character.isDigit('N'));
The method will provide boolean value.